# Cross-site publishing combine remote list into site search

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-search, cross-site-publishing, keyword-query-language

We are working with a cross-site publishing set up and that is all hooked up and working well for navigation and showing the catalog/list of entries on the publishing side. Actually we have two remote catalogs that are connected and both are working fine.

The problem is with a user-initiated search of the publishing site -- it doesn't return any results. And that would be because "technically" the contents of a managed catalog connection aren't on "this site." But from the **USER'S perspective** they are part of this site and should be included.

I see both remote catalogs as Site Collection search result sources and as Search (site) result sources. And the default search result source is the "Local SharePoint Results."

So my conception is that I want all three to be rolled up into the "default for search this site." It really should be transparent for the user. They shouldn't need to have special knowledge of how we arranged the information for them to search it.

How can I go about setting that up? How do I combine multiple search results into one search this site?

Comment: I may have made some progress. At the site collection level I created a new search result source that combined (to the best of my abilities) the queries from my Local SharePoint Results and my remove lists --- Products and Sessions catalogs.

I then added a search center subsite and set my custom result source as the default. Finally I went back to the Site Search Settings an configured the search navigation to direct "Our site" to the search center subsite.

Comment: For a few minutes I got the results I expected. Except the links to the items that came from the external catalogs looked like they pointed to the original catalog site location -- but when clicked they actually went to the publishing side location! Unfortunately I did something to break it and now I can't get it to work again. Darn.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I'm answering my own question.

At the top level of my site-collection (my prodcat site) I defined a new Result Source.

```
?{searchTerms} (contentclass:sts_listitem OR IsDocument:True) SPSiteUrl:https://sites.sp.example.com/teams/prodcat OR ListId:ae982b11-7ca7-42bd-b238-d960e3b248ed OR ListId:8e73face-390f-4286-8777-624cd2846053
```

The list IDs I copied out from the result sources automagically created when I connected the managed cross-site published lists.

I then created a basic search center subsite. Went in there and set the new source I had created as the default source for that site.

Finally I went back up to the top level and for the Search Settings in the search group (not the site collection administration group) configured a search navigation, directing "This site" to my basic search center url. And the Everything to our regular farm everything search page.

The results are a mixture of the pages that are actually on my prodcat site and remote list items coming through cross-site publishing!

The one problem is that the URLs shown in the results are for my catalog site, but when I click on themt hey change to my prodcat site. Crazy!